# Code base not finding standard C++ library header

Tags: c++, makefile, build, compilation

I am compiling an example application from the SDK repository of a third party vendor. I receive an error that one of the C++ header's (algorithm) cannot be found:

```
if [ ! -d .deps/ ]; then mkdir -p .deps/; fi
/opt/llvm-3.8.0/bin/clang++ -M -isystem/opt/tbricks/sdk/include64 -I../../.. -I../../../.. -I./../../../.. -DLINUX -DLINUX64 -DTB_USE_RCU -DURCU_INLINE_SMALL_FUNCTIONS -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DNDEBUG -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -fPIC -D_GNU_SOURCE -DTB_USE_RCU -DTB_USE_RCU -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -m64 --gcc-toolchain=/opt/gcc-5.2.0 -flto=full -std=gnu++14 -D_GLIBCXX_DEPRECATED= -pipe -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only -pthread -march=core2 -mtune=corei7 -g -O3 -Qunused-arguments -fnon-call-exceptions -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wno-self-assign -Wno-unused-function -Wno-gnu-empty-initializer -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-mismatched-tags -Wno-unused-local-typedef -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-unused-private-field -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-braces -Werror=return-type -Werror=overloaded-virtual -DSTRATEGY_BUILD_PROFILE=\"release\" ../../../../shared/Helpers.cpp > .deps/Helpers.o.d
../../../../shared/Helpers.cpp:14:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
#include <algorithm>
```

What sets the location path to search for C++ header files, such as algorithm? Is there anything I can grep for within makefiles?

Comment: Looks like you installed llvm/clang "by hand". Have you also installed libc++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either install g++ alongside (you need `libstdc++`) or use LLVM libc++ and specify it with `-stdlib=libc++`